# how to include a greater than Date in a JPA query?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have a JPA based project like so:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="events")
public class Event implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
  private String data;
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  private java.util.Date eventDate;

/* ... getters & setters */
}
```

In my DAO I do this:

```
public void checkForEvents(String text, java.util.Date myDate) {

  String query = "SELECT e FROM Event e WHERE e.data LIKE '%?1%' AND e.eventDate > ?2";
  Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(query);
  q.setParameter(1, text);
  q.setParameter(2, myDate);
  q.getSingleResult() /* and so on ... */

}
```

When I run the DAO code I get this error:

`The parameter "0" is of type "java.lang.String", but the declaration in the query is for type "java.util.Date".`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message looks strange, but the error is in the first argument. You can only pass values as parameters, so you should replace `e.data LIKE '%?1%'` by `e.data LIKE ?1`, and surround your text with `%` in the Java code.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's somehow related to the fact that you cannot use parameters inside literals (i.e. `'%?1%'`).

Try the following query instead:

```
SELECT e FROM Event e WHERE e.data LIKE CONCAT('%', ?1, '%') AND e.eventDate > ?2
```

Comment: Thanks for the right answer, @JBNizet got in just ahead of you.